# how to make different types of report in one sql statement?

Tags: sql, view, dynamic-sql

I need to make a query that makes a report using different tables, based on a value of one field.

This value affects the 'select' as well as the 'from' and 'where'.

At first I thought using dynamic SQL, but since the 'from' and 'where' are also changing it won't work.

Now I'm thinking about making views for all the different report types and I have 2 questions about is, since I'm pretty new with this:

1. how do I use the views in the main query?
2. is there a better idea that could work for the problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> how do I use the views in the main query?

Just like every table.

> is there a better idea that could work for the problem?

I don't know if it's better but you can use UNION (if number of columns in every report is equal and their types are the same).